# Android - sharedpreferences for radio button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I am struggling implementing a sharedpreference for my radio button, I am trying to save the state of a radio button but when I run my emulator a blank screen appears and everything on the page disappears ... any help will be appreciated

Here is my code:

on create

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, ViewGroup radioGroup) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_system);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
    RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
    savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

calling the method

```
    RadioGroup gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.question1);

    gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.answer1A:
                ans1 = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.answer1B:
                ans1 = 2;
                break;
            }
            SavePreferences("SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX", checkedId);

        }
```

the method

```
        private void SavePreferences(String key, int value){
              SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
              editor.putInt(key, value);
              editor.commit(); 
             }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to set the id as position , try this

```
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
     int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX,R.id.answer1A);
     gender.check(savedRadioIndex);
```

instead of

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
    RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
    savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
        String radio_value;
        int val;


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getString("KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX", "");
    RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
    savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);



        val=Integer.ParseInt(savedRadioIndex);
        savedCheckedRadioButton.check(val);
```

Hope this may help you!